# I thought I understood Normal Forms

Tags: database, normalization, database-normalization

I'm studying a diploma of web development online, and I've just gotten into database design and development. I thought I understood Normal Forms, but I just reached a question that stopped me in my tracks.

> Look at the following list of attributes for the customer entity:
>
> ```
> Customer(cus_ID, name, address, mobile_phone)
> ```
>
> Why is this entity not in 3NF?

As far as I can tell, it *is* in 3NF. All the attributes wouldn't be there if it wasn't for the customer, the name, address and mobile data sets require the customer to exist.

Have I just got the entire concept of 3NF wrong?

Comment: I suspect maybe `address` could be normalized away as different customers might share the same address.

Comment: A single customer could have multiple phones (as well as multiple customers having a single address).  If the customer ID identifies a family, then you could have multiple names per ID too.  You need more information to come up with a good answer.  What are the functional dependencies?  What are the cardinalities of the relationships between attributes?  If that's the entire question, then it is a bad question.  Your only problem is reading too much into the information given and not recognizing that it is not answerable as it stands — which is hard.

Comment: Re "All the attributes wouldn't be there if it wasn't for the customer, the name, address and mobile data sets require the customer to exist." Normalization is not about entities or attributes "having to exist". It is about (splitting relations into projections) (eliminating certain) functional dependencies and join dependencies. (Entity-Relationship information modeling has a notion of "weak entity" but that has nothing to do with normalization.) So it looks like you have "got the entire concept of 3NF wrong".

Comment: @Dai: Decomposing because "different customers might share the same address" is not normalization. Normalizing can't add new attributes (eg addressid if you mean that). Nor requires removing a FD (functional dependency) on a CK (candidate key) (eg removing address and adding a table with customer and address if you mean that). Ie removing a JD (join dependency) implied by a CK. Normalizing to 5NF is *defined* as having no JDs *except* those ones. If all customers sharing an address have to share all the addresses of a *set* (ie an MVD ie 2-way JD) then that violates 4NF (but not 3NF).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks odd at first, but you have not defined what goes into address or even the id. Some possibilities for this to violate 3NF that comes to mind are (in addition to other comments and answers that you may get here):

1. If the id is the mobile phone number itself.
2. If the customer has more than one mobile phone or more than one address that the business is interested in capturing [Source of this point](http://bestanswerzone.net/database-question/).
3. If the address would include some communication methods including a mobile phone.
4. If the mobile phone number can be circulated across users somehow. For example the number may not have to be unique across countries/carriers (I am not a Telco expert).
5. If the address contains a country, city and state information and mobile phone number is allowed to contain Area Code as part of it (which would depend on country, city and state information).

Edit:
I had originally included this point but @philipxy suggested otherwise in the note below:
"If any of the attributes are found in other parts of the database not shown here."

Comment: 6 is wrong and should be removed. Normalization of a relation variable has nothing to do with other relation variables. (Quality of design does involve the whole database.)

Answer (score 2):

Multiple customers could have the same address.

Comment: While that's true, it has nothing to do with normalization.

Answer (score 1):

Each answer previously given makes hypotheses over the meaning of your data. But to know if a schema is or not in 3NF, the only correct answer is: "Show me the functional dependencies of the schema, and then I can *proof* if the schema is in 3NF or not". This is because the 3FN is a formal concept, and has sense *only* in a formal context.

So maybe the question should have been posed in a different way:

> Given this schema, under realistic hypotheses, which are the functional dependencies?

And then from these functional dependencies one can *know*, and not *speculate* over a normal form.

So, in my opinion, a course in which no one taught you what are the functional dependencies, and ask you if a certain relation is in 3NF or not, is not a good course.

Answer (score 0):

From a certain point of view this table doesn't qualify for third-normal form because it's not in first-normal form. "Mobile" phone? What other types of phones might there be? "Address" ? Which address - home, business, where-the-yacht-is-docked, etc? Name - what are the sub-fields of name (first, middle, last - and oh, is there a title such as Dr. or Mr. or Herr Doktor Ingeneur in there too?)?

Comment: I don't know that I'm supposed to look that far into it, as its very early into the database unit. My mind went straight too the issue of multiple types of phones but my lecturer shut that down by saying it simply wasn't the problem I'm supposed to be fixing, which I feel is wrong. These questions should fully flesh out the the possibilities of different phones, the extra parts of an address and what not.

Comment: @Slappy &  Bob Jarvis: Notions of "normalized" or "1NF" involving attributes being considered heterogeneous or homogeneous collections is not relevant to normalization. As it is used in normalization, all relation variables are in 1NF.